# Why for loop on jquery is not working on thymeleaf?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am a beginner in Thymeleaf.

In my Spring project, I am using thymeleaf. But `for` loop is not working. This is my code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var page = $("#page").val();
        for (var i = 1; i < page; i++) {
            // ...
        }
    });

</script>
```

Without `for` loop it is working , but after adding it, it shows error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing
>   document: template="householdlist", line 78 - column 18

Where is the problem?

Comment: Does `$('#page').val()` definitely return a value?

Comment: yes, it does. I check it

Comment: Show more of your code, specifically the bit that the error is pointing to! - Your household list template, let's have a look.

Comment: Ok,I am editing my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var page = $("#page").val();
    for(var i=1;i< page;i++){

    }
  });
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```